# How to write code for symmetric Mutual Information (MI) similarity measure?

Tags: matlab, math, image-processing, statistics

The function below calculates symmetric Mutual Information, Jeffrey Divergence, between 2 images histogram `XI` and `XJ`. The below code is open source but I think its result isn't accurate or I can't understand it. However, it uses same as [Wikipedia function](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/7cc6adb9fae79b753f0b89cd824478767c440c37) which is written in a different way than [Xu, Xiaocong, et al, 2016](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0924271616304324) paper which I try reproduces its result.

```
function d=jeffrey_divergence(XI,XJ)
% Implementation of the Jeffrey Divergence
% (cf. "The Earth Movers' Distance as a Metric for Image Retrieval",
%      Y. Rubner, C. Tomasi, L.J. Guibas, 2000)
%
% @author: B. Schauerte
% @date:   2009
% @url:    http://cvhci.anthropomatik.kit.edu/~bschauer/
% Copyright 2009 B. Schauerte. All rights reserved.
% 
% Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without 
% modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are 
% met:
% 
%    1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright 
%       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
% 
%    2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright 
%       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in 
%       the documentation and/or other materials provided with the 
%       distribution.
% 
% THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY B. SCHAUERTE ''AS IS'' AND ANY EXPRESS OR 
% IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED 
% WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE 
% DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL B. SCHAUERTE OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE 
% FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR 
% CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF 
% SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR 
% BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, 
% WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR
% OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF
% ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
% 
% The views and conclusions contained in the software and documentation
% are those of the authors and should not be interpreted as representing 
% official policies, either expressed or implied, of B. Schauerte.
m=size(XJ,1); % number of samples of p
p=size(XI,2); % dimension of samples
assert(p == size(XJ,2)); % equal dimensions
assert(size(XI,1) == 1); % pdist requires XI to be a single sample
d=zeros(m,1); % initialize output array
for i=1:m
  for j=1:p
    m=(XJ(i,j) + XI(1,j)) / 2;
            if m ~= 0  % if m == 0, then xi == xj == 0
                d(i,1) = d(i,1) + (XI(1,j) * log(XI(1,j) / m)) + (XJ(i,j)*log(XJ(i,j) / m));
            end
  end
end
```

How I can resolve this issue?

Update:

The paper equation is reimplemented on light of MI
[image]

Thanks

source 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39275-histogram-distances?focused=3786741&tab=function

Comment: Integration is a summation for a discrete signal.  The code looks like it's summing.  Why do you believe it is not right?  Provide more details.

Comment: In this question, I focused on the main function but I explain my problem in more details  [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/352581-images-similarity-measure-using-j-divergence). Unfortunately no one has ans

Comment: @rayryeng How can code [this function](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/7cc6adb9fae79b753f0b89cd824478767c440c37) using Matlab? thanks

Comment: The code in your post does that. However, the formula linked does not divide by `m`. I'm not sure why that is being done in the code as it's not represented in the formula. Perhaps remove the division by `m` and try again.